# Unable to set data attribute of true or false using Sightly data

Tags: aem, sightly

I'm trying to set a data attribute with a value of true/false using `Sightly` but its always removing the attribute from the div. I can hardcode the true or false and it works but using `Sightly` it just removes it.

code example

```
<div data-video-controls="${videoPlayer.videoControls}"></div>
```

It just returns

```
<div></div>
```

I've also tried the context but still to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems there is a bug in the way how Sightly handles boolean-named string `${'false'}`. Consider following examples:

```
// Example 1
In:  <div true1="${true}" false1="${false}">
Out: <div true1>

// Example 2
In:  <div true2="true" false2="false">
Out: <div true2="true" false2="false">

// Example 3 - bug
In:  <div true3="${'true'}" false3="${'false'}">
Out: <div true3="true">
```

Example 1 shows that if you assign `${true}` or `${false}` boolean to the attribute, the attribute will be shown (valueless) or hidden. Example 2 isn't surprising - it's a normal HTML.

**Example 3 presents the bug**. We use `${'true'}` and `${'false'}` string literals and they should be presented as any other strings (eg. `${'hello world'}`). `${'true'}` works predictably, but `${'false'}` is evaluated (like `${false}`) and it hides the attribute. I wasn't able to produce a Sightly attribute that would produce something like: `attr="false"`.

If it worked correctly, you could transform the `Boolean` into a `String` using the ternary operator:

```
<div data-video-controls="${videoPlayer.videoControls ? 'true' : 'false'}"></div>
```

Because of the bug it produces correct results only for the `videoControls == true`. Otherwise it hides the attribute.

Comment: So I guess I can work around at the moment but will raise it with Adobe as a bug.

Comment: I confirm this issue, which will get fixed. Thanks Tomek for the workaround!

Comment: This issue will be fixed with AEM6 SP2 that is going to be released in January 2015.

Comment: It's also possible to set the context to 'text', or another context which might suit your use case better. This way the boolean value will be rendered as text and the false value will be displayed:
`${videoPlayer.videoControls @ context='text'}`

Comment: Thanks this worked for me (5 years later with AEM 6.4) @TomMaton was the bug ever raised?

Comment: Been 8 years now, this issue with AEM still persists and taking up our time to eventually find that its a bug with AEM! @NielsInc solution works though, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[NielsInc mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207283/unable-to-set-data-attribute-of-true-or-false-using-sightly-data/45613076#comment72380411_25208712) the following in the comments:

> It's also possible to set the context to 'text', or another context which might suit your use case better. This way the boolean value will be rendered as text and the false value will be displayed: `${videoPlayer.videoControls @ context='text'}`

Using `${videoPlayer.videoControls @ context='text'}` worked for me.